# Does changing from insecure to secure boot affect the running of third party software?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, uefi, rtl8723be

Recently I dual booted my laptop with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
There were issues with the wireless-Realtek driver RTL8723BE which were solved by disabling secure boot and following the commands given in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304607)

Now the wifi works fine. But now if I were to change boot option to UEFI will it affect the system in any way? (will wifi stop working again?)

Comment: When asking a question, you need to have all information needed to understand you in the question body. Don't expect us to open external links to understand what you did. Especially not when your link is to page 1 of an 11-page thread on the forums! What commands did you follow? What exactly did you do? Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable Secure Boot, all unsigned third-party kernel modules including rt8723be, proprietary video drivers, VirtualBox and others will stop loading.

In general Secure Boot is a useless feature. I do not see any reasons to enable it.

Comment: while some issues might occur with secure boot which only can be solved by disabling it, I still strongly disagree with your opinion about it being useless.
IF your system is running fine with secure boot (given all hardware is supported by signed kernel modules) this feature will prevent most attempts on loading customized kernel modules to compromise the systems integrity.

Comment: And what is the "usefullness" of SB? Protect from boot viruses? Have you  you seen any of those in the last decade?

Comment: Custom kernel modules can be loaded only by admin using `sudo`. There is no reason to protect the system any other ways.

Comment: there is: due to bugs within user- or kernelspace a user might be able to gain root permissions without the machines owners consent and would in your case be able to load a kernel module. But with secure boot enabled this would require the attacker to disable sb first, which would in most cases involve physical access to the system, access to the efi and a reboot.

Comment: If an attacker gets full control over the system, there is no need to install kernel modules ;-)

Comment: that is for the attacker and its intentions to decide, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: If KazWolfe sees you calling Secure Boot useless...  (I agree with you BTW)